# JDBC SQLite not enforcing unique primary key constraint

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc, primary-key

Can anyone suggest to me why my SQLite JDBC database is not enforcing the unique primary key constraint?

The create table method is:

```
public static void TableCars()
      {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:WalkerTechCars.db");
          System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

          stmt = c.createStatement();
          String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CARS3 " +
                       "(REGISTRATION TEXT PRIMRY KEY   NOT NULL, " + 
                       " PHONE               TEXT       NOT NULL," +
                       " MAKE                TEXT       NOT NULL, " + 
                       " MODEL               TEXT, " + 
                       " COLOUR              TEXT)";
          stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
          stmt.close();
          c.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
          System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Cars3 created successfully");
      }
```

The insert method is:

```
 public static void InsertCars(String table, String phone, String registration, String make, String model, String colour)
  {
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:WalkerTechCars.db");
      c.setAutoCommit(false);
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

      String query="INSERT INTO "+table+" (PHONE,REGISTRATION,MAKE, MODEL,COLOUR) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

      pstmt = c.prepareStatement(query);

      pstmt = c.prepareStatement
              ("insert into CARS3 values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setString(1,registration);
        pstmt.setString(2,phone);
        pstmt.setString(3, make);
        pstmt.setString(4, model);
        pstmt.setString(5, colour);         
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        pstmt.close();
      c.commit();
      c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Car Records created successfully");
  }
```

and the line of code that should not be allowed, but can be executed repeatedly is:

```
DbHandler.InsertCars("Cars3", "1","BN51 MZY", "Mini", "C220", "BLACK");
```

Comment: Are you saying that there is no error message printed from this `InsertCars` method?

Comment: As mentioned... you're query has 'PRIMRY KEY'

Answer (score 5):

Your creation SQL states `PRIMRY KEY` instead [`PRIMARY KEY`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html). Your table was thus, initially created without the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint and since you added the 'IF NOT EXISTS' condition, new creations won't wake effect until the table is previously dropped.

The reason your table was created without `PRIMARY KEY` constraint can be found within the `column-constraint` diagram:

[image]

The constraint deffinition is wrong (`PRMARY` is not `PRIMARY`),  (as remarked in red)  that makes the column constraint sub-grammar not to triggered.

Comment: I think he would still get the message about either invalid syntax (SQLite checks for the proper constraint syntax), or from trying to create an already existing table.

Comment: Although this might be the cause, I would have expected this to raise either a syntax error or an exception noting that the table already existed. As it is currently phrased your answer looks more like a comment for clarification than an actual answer.

Comment: @laalto If that is true, then I'd say that is a bug in the parser of SQLite. Note that I agree it is probably an answer to this question, the way it is phrased makes it look more like a comment.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have just re-checked and laalto is right, it doesn't cause syntax error.

Comment: This is because SQLite allows pretty much anything as a declared column type and so the `PRIMRY KEY` becomes the datatype for this column...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not a bug but a feature. If you inspect the grammar diagrams at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html carefully, you'll notice that a type-name can consist of arbitrary number of parts and in this case it goes to the column-constraint part only when encountering "NOT NULL".

Comment: @laalto: By the way: http://geekwhisperin.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/bug-vs-feature.jpg

Comment: @laalto Wow, didn't know that. If Pablo gives his answer more body by including this I will upvote :)

Comment: It was the syntax error meaning it was not registering the primary key. Now I have corrected it and made a new version of the table,  if I try to duplicate the primary key it gives the error [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: CARS4.REGISTRATION)

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo You're not reading the diagrams correctly.

Comment: @laalto Checked, is that PRMARY KEY doesn't match any branch of column-constraint sub-grammar and thus is skipped ...

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo Tokens `PRMARY` and `KEY` don't trigger the `column-constraint` grammar and get consumed by the `name` loop in `type-name`. `IF NOT EXISTS` is often a code smell but not the root cause here.